# Emoji font needed

Tags: android, emoji, android-fonts

I implement chat app, and need good font to represent emoji items on androids from 4.0. Standart font is not good, many emojies are missing on early androids(4.0, 4.1, 4.2). 
So far I found one good font -

```
https://github.com/MorbZ/OpenSansEmoji
```

but it has an issue - all amojies are in one color (color of textView, if it is in it) and not colorful. Please, if anyone now somw powerful font, wich works on all androids >4.0 and have colorful emoji, please share with us

Thnks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out easy way to do this - 
I just used third party solution - https://github.com/rockerhieu/emojicon

Yet, since I have got my own design of emoji keyboard, I just used two things from that lib - EmojiconTextView-s for emoji btns and chat elements for text.
EmojiconEditText - etMessage(where user do message input)
I filled emoji btns with unicode code of each smile, and received pretty absolutely customized emoji keyboard!

If anyone need emoji code list, I can attach xml file, which i did parse to receive codes.